# Firewall rule name is different than supplied in command

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have written a small script which creates VPC, firewall-rule, and instance. I gave parameters to script. but instead of taking parameter for firewall-rule it takes instancename2 value in firewall name field which.

```
ZONE=$2
MACHINE_TYPE=$3
IMAGE_FAMILY=$4
IMAGE_PROJECT=$5
BOOT_DISK_SIZE=$6
BOOT_DISK_TYPE=$7
NETWORK_NAME=$8
FIREWALL_RULE=$9
FIREWALL_NAME=$10
TAGS=$11
gcloud compute networks create $NETWORK_NAME --subnet-mode=auto
gcloud compute firewall-rules create $FIREWALL_NAME --network=$NETWORK_NAME --allow=$FIREWALL_RULE --source-tags=$TAGS
gcloud compute instances create $INSTANCE_NAME \
    --zone=$ZONE \
    --machine-type=$MACHINE_TYPE \
    --image-family=$IMAGE_FAMILY \
    --image-project=$IMAGE_PROJECT \
    --boot-disk-size=$BOOT_DISK_SIZE \
    --boot-disk-type=$BOOT_DISK_TYPE \
    --network-interface network=$NETWORK_NAME,no-address \
    --tags=$TAGS \


command : bash network.sh myvm us-west1-a f1-micro ubuntu-1810 ubuntu-os-cloud 10 pd-ssd mynetwork tcp:80 myrule mytag

output :
Created .
NAME       SUBNET_MODE  BGP_ROUTING_MODE  IPV4_RANGE  GATEWAY_IPV4
mynetwork  AUTO         REGIONAL

Instances on this network will not be reachable until firewall rules
are created. As an example, you can allow all internal traffic between
instances as well as SSH, RDP, and ICMP by running:

$ gcloud compute firewall-rules create <FIREWALL_NAME> --network mynetwork --allow tcp,udp,icmp --source-ranges <IP_RANGE>
$ gcloud compute firewall-rules create <FIREWALL_NAME> --network mynetwork --allow tcp:22,tcp:3389,icmp

Creating firewall...⠛Created 
Creating firewall...done.                                                                                      
NAME   NETWORK    DIRECTION  PRIORITY  ALLOW   DENY  DISABLED
myvm0  mynetwork  INGRESS    1000      tcp:80        False
Created.
NAME  ZONE        MACHINE_TYPE  PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP  EXTERNAL_IP  STATUS
myvm  us-west1-a  f1-micro                   10.138.0.2                RUNNING

please check the name of firewall created (below 'creating firewall...done.'). It's not what i provided in command. Its similar to INSTANCE_NAME variable.
```

Comment: What is the value of $12? The error is stating that your protocol is wrong. $12 should look like `tcp:80` You also have not specified `--source-ranges=` unless you intend for all traffic `0.0.0.0/0`.

Comment: i gave `tcp:80` for $12, but script takes $1 value i.e. if $1 is myvm then $12 takes myvm2

Comment: I do not understand your comment. Clarify (edit) your question with the actual values.

Comment: I have changed the question..

Comment: When running your script add debugging. Example: `bash -x network.sh myvm` plus your other command line options. Then review the command executed and the output. Simple debugging.